# How to put background in a navigation bar

Tags: css, list, html, background, nav

I am trying to put a solid white background behind this navagation bar so when it scrolls it does not show whats behind it.

[CodePen Example of Bar](http://codepen.io/enoughsev/pen/vAJCo) | http://codepen.io/enoughsev/pen/vAJCo

```
    <div id="header">
    <img id="nav_img" src="Graphics/nav_img.svg" height="122" width="201" alt="Lanier Canoe and Kayak Club logo"/> 
        <div id="nav_bar" style:"color:#FFF;">
            <header id="title">Lanier Canoe and Kayak Club</header>
            <ul id="nav_words">
            <a href="#" id="menu_item"><li class="selected items">Home</li></a>
            <a href="#" id="menu_item"><li class="items">About Us</li></a>
            <a href="#" id="menu_item"><li class="items">Programs</li></a>
            <a href="#" id="menu_item"><li class="items">Rentals</li></a>
            <a href="#" id="menu_item"><li class="items">Contact Us</li></a>
            </ul>
        </div>
</div>
```

In theory I should be able to just put

```
#header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    padding-bottom:20px;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    border:
    z-index: 3;
    color:white;
}
```

and it work properly correct?

Answer (score 0):

Give fixed position to header :- [DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rBpAG)

```
#header {
position: fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there is `position:fixed` currety `navbar` is not part of #header. So HTML structure should be altered a bit.

- Add `position:fixed` to `#header` instead of nav bar
- Add a paernt div for `body content` part and give `top margin` (margin top = header
  height)

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/IPAWuvOS/2/)**